# Camera not rotating properly

Tags: android, android-camera

I have implemented camera by using [This Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) but the camera preview is not working well. If the device is in Landscape mode, the preview shows in Potrait mode and vice versa. and the image is stretched too. Here is the [Screen Shot](http://postimg.org/image/zedbd5415/). This was taken when device was in potrait mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is displayed in form of link on the same page.
Please refer the link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)